# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to populate a dropdow list from a data base table,

i'm getting this error :

> > There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'QuartierId'.
> >
> > Description : Une exception non gérée s'est produite au moment de l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Contrôlez la trace de la pile pour plus d'informations sur l'erreur et son origine dans le code.
> >
> > Détails de l'exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'QuartierId'.

here my Model **"QuartierSet"** :

```
   public partial class Quartier
{
    public Quartier()
    {
        this.Publication = new HashSet<Publication>();
    }

    public int Quartier_Id { get; set; }
    public string Quartier_Libelle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Publication> Publication { get; set; }
    public virtual Ville Ville { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller Side:

```
 public ActionResult CreateOffreLocation(OffreLocation offreLocation)
    {
        try
        {

            ViewBag.QuartierId = new SelectList(db.QuartierSet, "Quartier_Id", "Quartier_Libelle");
            db.PublicationSet.Add(offreLocation);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ListOffreLocation");

        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error");
        }
    }
```

My view Side :

```
       @Html.DropDownList("QuartierId", String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ViewBag` is only available from the action in which you set it to the view of its action.

After setting in `ViewBag` you are redirecting to another action due to which the `ViewBag` is set to `null` again.

You need to add the following line in the **ListOffreLocation** action  instead of **CreateOffreLocation**:

```
ViewBag.QuartierId = new SelectList(db.QuartierSet, "Quartier_Id", "Quartier_Libelle");
```

Comment: Or just add this line ViewBag.QuartierId = new SelectList(db.QuartierSet, "Quartier_Id", "Quartier_Libelle"); to a new action called ListOffreLocation and just return the view which makes a lot more sense

Comment: my " ListOffreLocation" return the list of location offers, i don't see why i have to put the viewBag there, i don't need the dropdown list there ,  public ActionResult ListOffreLocation()
        {
            
            return View(db.PublicationSet.OfType<OffreLocation>().ToList());
        }

Comment: you have dropdownlist in the view of ``ListOffreLocation`` action right

Comment: No the "ListOffreLocation" is an action that returns a list of registrations from my data base, in the create action i need to populate a dropdown list from a small table called " quartier" with the name of streets, after validating the creation form i redirecte the navigation the "ListOffreLocation" view ... Hope that you get my point !

Comment: but in create action you are not returning view

Comment: return RedirectToAction("ListOffreLocation"); !

Comment: yes, you are redirecting to another action and viewbag becomes null when control reaches view

Comment: Yes, because after creating, i don't need any more the creation form that contain the dropdown list

Comment: then you need to put this line the get action you are missing it there i suspect

Comment: Yes, It works Now! in Fact i have to put the bagView in the get action instead of the post action

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownList((SelectListItem)ViewBag.QuartierId, String.Empty)
```

Comment: Though arguably a fine answer, consider adding a description to it. Thanks